# Conditional hls playlist redirection in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, curl, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to conditionally redirect a playlist request to one list or another depending of the status of a streaming channel.

Right now, this is what I'm testing, and it doesn't play anything. I tried to call it with VLC and Kodi. My purpose is to make this work so I can redirect to an alternate stream if a stream is offline.

CURL follows the redirection, and the Kodi logs indicate that it also follows the redirect, but doesn't play anything, being streaming live or offline.

This is the code of [this script](http://vivo.pichilemutv.org/streamurl.php). You can call it with CURL so you can checkout what's going on. Or copy this code and tryit with your own streams.

```
<?php
$stream_status = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/canal3pichilemu-stream/getValueOf/status?key=<my_key>"));

if($stream_status->results == "offline") {
  header("Location: http://vivo.pichilemutv.org/offline/playlist.m3u8", false, 302);
} else {
  header("Location: http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/15179897/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8", false, 302);
}

die();
```

I'd like to know what am I missing, because redirection seems to work, but streams doesn't play.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I have same problem with kodi and vlc not playing the redirect stream!

Answer (score 0):

VLC 2.1.4 follows the redirect and starts the playback. Assuming your source streams are OK then it may be a bug in Kodi. Check the log for the actual media segment GET requests and see if they're valid.